# Genymotion: possible to create a shortcut to an Android virtual device?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Genymotion as Android emulator, but would like to be able to start a virtual device from the command line or with a Windows shortcut, instead of the Genymotion window.

Because Genymotion uses Oracle VirtualBox, I can start the virtual machine from explorer, but then it doesn't use the special interface of Genymotion.

Is it possible to start a Genymotion-device without starting the Genymotion GUI first?

Answer (score 5):

You can find a solution here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768489/how-to-start-genymotion-device-with-shell-command/18773118#18773118).

The command line you need to launch is:

```
player --vm-name <VM id | VM name>
```

The VMs id and name can be found from command line using this code:

```
VBoxManage list vms
```

It displays a list of your Virtual Box machines on this format: `name {id}`.